# Vue2 Element-UI Datepicker set editable property to date-rage textbox

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, element-ui

As per documentation in [Element UI - datetime-picker](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/datetime-picker) it is possible to set "editable" property to whole datetime-picker control.

But I want to set "editable" property to false to the textbox control inside datetime-picker when someone click on the control

How can I stop user to not edit the textbox inside date-picker control?

For e.g.
[image]

```
 <el-date-picker
            v-model="defaultValue"
            type="datetimerange"
            :picker-options="monthlyOptions"
            :value-format="valueFormat"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            range-separator="To"
            start-placeholder="Start date"
            end-placeholder="End date"
            :disabled="disabled"
            align="center"
            :editable="false">
    </el-date-picker>
```

Comment: Rather than using a date-time picker, maybe use a date picker + a time picker. That way, you'll be able to disable one or the other.

Comment: @kissu - Thanks for suggestion, but as of now we must stick with current design only. Any workaround with existing control?

Comment: Not a Element UI specialist (I don't work with it anymore) but splitting the 2 can be done gracefully with CSS IMO, the design could stay the same.